# Current value of flow in a network

Tags: graphs, network-flow

Confused about a question regarding flow networks.

**Question is:** *Given the network below, what is the current value of flow in this network?*
[image]

Does the current flow of a network refer to the maximum flow or something else?

Comment: The question is asking you how many units are flowing from $s$ to $t$.

Comment: Right, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is asking how many units are flowing from $s$ to $t$ under the current flow.

The *maximum flow* problem asks for the maximal number of units that can flow from $s$ to $t$ under *any* flow.